# OS Error While Installing XGBoost on Anaconda Jupyter Notebook 3.5 on Mac

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, xgboost

I installed XGBoost via this command:

```
pip install xgboost
```

It successfully installed.However i get this error message when i import it:

```
OSError: dlopen(/Users/Deepak/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/5/libgomp.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Deepak/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Help would truly be appreciated in resolving this issue !

Comment: Hey man i was wondering if you would know how to remedy this @jezrael

Answer (score 1):

this issue is on github now. [dmlc/xgboost/issues](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1446)

I think this is caused by gcc version. maybe you can try

```
brew install gcc5 --without-multilib
```

this works for me

Answer (score 0):

I installed xgboost with conda on my mac:

```
$ conda install xgboost
```